# Taking video and snapshots simultaneously using a webcam

Tags: command-line, video, webcam

I'm trying to do something fairly specific and I was wondering if anyone had some suggestions for ways to do it.

I'm working on a program and for it I need an application to do the following utilizing a webcam:

1. Be able to locally broadcast live video from a webcam to the user on the screen at a decent frame-rate (somewhere around 10 would be nice)
2. From this live broadcast, be able to take single image snapshots at a commanded time

I'm looking for something that runs on the command line, preferably. I've tried using VLC which is nice for the first part, but in order to take a screenshot, I haven't found a way to do so using the command line. In order for that to work in my application I would need to simulate keystrokes with an active window which may make it a bit difficult to implement.

If anyone has any other suggestions as well using basic terminal commands that would also work, I'm fully open to them.

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way to accomplish this, would be to do the exact opposite of what you're trying to do:

- first [capture still pictures](https://askubuntu.com/questions/106770/take-a-picture-from-terminal)
- then [convert those still pictures to a video](https://askubuntu.com/questions/458442/merge-multiple-jpegs-into-one-video)

(so basically a combination of both above answers)

I would: take a minimum of 16 fps as that is [the minimum our brain needs to see smooth motion](http://www.tested.com/art/movies/452387-48-fps-and-beyond-how-high-frame-rates-affect-perception/)

If this is for a web application, you wouldn't even have to convert these still images to a video stream as you could use JavaScript to display 16 images every second (refresh page 16 times per second) provided you've got enough bandwidth available to upload 16 pictures / second. But that depends on your specific use case.

Comment: @Favvy - sadly it sometimes applied to 1+ users... using JavaScript can have problems as lots of lag can occur between frames (even when doing them at 1 every 2 seconds), unless all the images are cached or something which can take a while. nice answer :)

Comment: @Wilf: :D :D :D Like I said: bandwidth would play a pertinent role, but as the OP didn't give a lot of information on his use case, that's the best I can come up with using the little information I have.